# Pandas groupby plot with different X-Axis order

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm working on `titanic.csv`, and trying to make some plots. Running into one issue. How can I re-organize the x-axis to place the same pclass value next to each other.

my current code:

```
titanic.groupby(['Sex', 'Pclass'])['Survived'].mean().plot(kind='bar', color=my_colors)
```

produce the following chart: 
[image]

I'd like to place the male and female from same class next to each other to show the difference in survival rate. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order of columns in groupby:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

my_colors = ['r','g','b','k','y','magenta']
titanic.groupby(['pclass', 'sex'])['survived'].mean().plot(kind='bar', color=my_colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or you can stack the bars:

```
titanic.groupby(['pclass', 'sex'])['survived'].mean().unstack('sex').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Why you use `mean` instead of `count`?

Comment: I use mean to calculate the survival rate of each group

Answer (score 0):

Altair can be very handy here. Here are 3 different one-liners to produce three different visualisations of this dataset.

```
import seaborn as sns
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

from altair import *
```

#### First viz.

```
Chart(titanic).mark_bar().encode(x='pclass:O', y='mean(survived)', column='sex').configure_cell(width=200, height=200)
```

[image]

#### Second viz.

```
Chart(titanic).mark_bar().encode(x='sex:N', y='mean(survived):Q',  column='pclass:O').configure_facet_cell(
        strokeWidth=0.0).configure_cell(width=200, height=200)
```

[image]

#### Third viz.

```
Chart(titanic).mark_bar().encode(x='pclass:O', y='mean(survived):Q',  color='sex:O').configure_cell(width=200, height=200)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. didn't know about altair, looks super helpful!